# Android : How can i settag for the images which are in gridview?

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me how can I setTag and getTag for the images which are in gridview.
I have written the following code, but it doesn't work. Is the following code correct or not?

```
int jj=100;
    for(int j=0;j<imageid.length;j++)//imageid is the array of drawable images
        {
        griview1.getChildAt(j).setTag(jj);
        System.out.println(g.getChildAt(j).getTag());
        }
```

this is my getView method

```
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ImageView imv;
    if(arg1!=null)
    {
        imv=(ImageView)arg1;
    }
    else
    {
        imv=new ImageView(cont);
        imv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(40,40));
        imv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imv.setPadding(0,0,0,0);

        }

    }
    imv.setImageResource(imageid[arg0]);
    return imv;
```

Comment: you've already made a post like this before and a very valid response was presented to you. if you're going to get anywhere, post your custom adapter. let's see what you're doing in `getView()`

Comment: i'am really sorry mate,by mistake i deleted the previous post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally myself i got the answer for my question.Thank you for all who gave their valuable suggestions.

> in the Grid-view's listener only i set the tags for the grid-view cells by checking the condition

```
for example:    
if(position==20)

g.setTag("our tag");
```

Answer (score 0):

simply set your tags inside the `getView`

```
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

    if(arg1!=null)
    {
        ImageView imv = new ImageView(cont);
        imv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(40,40));
        imv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imv.setPadding(0,0,0,0);

        arg1 = imv;
    }
    arg1.setTag(arg0);
    return arg1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this mate.but I've already tried this.I want to set My Own tags instead of the positions(i.e., here arg0).

Comment: well it's certainly possible. you can set any object as your tag. what did you have in mind as to your own tag? if you need all these tags different but at specific positions, perhaps you'd have an indexed collection of objects with what tag at what position.